# Recursive Find Big O time complexity

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

I am learning about time complexity and I trying to figure out a relationship. My lecture notes describe a recursive find functions as :

```
find(array A, item I)
  if(arrayEmpty(A)) return BAD;
  if(item == A[0]) return GOOD;
  return find(allButFirst(A), I);
```

useful link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cG5KZSn1LE

My notes says that the starting relationship for time complexity is as a follow:

```
T(n) = 1 + T(n-1) // I understand this
T(1) = 1 // only one computation, understandable
```

then we unroll T(n)

```
T(N) = 1 + 1 + T(n-2) // every recursive step 1 comparison plus recursive call
T(N) = 1 + 1 + 1 + T(n-3) 
T(N) = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + T(n-4) 
...
T(N) = (n - 1) + T(n-(n-1)) // This point I am lost how they got this generalisation
```

If someone can explain how the above relation was generalised to  T(N) = (n - 1) + T(n-(n-1)) and perhaps with a example would be better for clarity.

For example I want to try the above relationship with some values so let's say A {1, 2, 3} and I = 3

then here are the following computation

```
1 + T(n-1) // {2,3}
1 + 1 + T(n-2) // {3}
1 // {3} Found
```

So for above we had total 3 comparison and 2 recursive calls. So I would say the relationship is T(n) = n + t(n-(n-1)) = n + t(1) = n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each step of the unrolled pattern, if we are `k` steps into the recursion (for the first step, `k=1`, the last step, `k=n`), there are `k` 1's.

In the expansion you posted, the last line, `T(N) = (n - 1) + T(n-(n-1))` is the second-to-last step, since `T(n-(n-1))` expands to `T(1)`, so for that line, `k=n-1`.

So there are `n-1` 1's in that line, hence the `(n-1)` term.

Likewise, the parameter passed to `T` at the `k`th step is `n` minus the current step, since it's the number of steps remaining. For the first row, that's `n-k = n-1`, hence `T(n-1)`. For the second-to-last step, it's `n-k = n-(n-1)`, hence `T(n-(n-1)) = T(1)`.